# Unable to connect to Vagrant private network from host - Destination host unreachable

Tags: networking, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I'm trying to set my Virtualbox VM running with Vagrant. So far I have been unable to connect to the machine.

I'm using Vagrant 2.2.4 and Virtualbox 6.0.8r130520 (official Oracle package for Debian/Ubuntu 18: deb [arch=amd64] http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian bionic contrib")

I'm using a private network with static ip [link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html#static-ip) in my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
```

Additionally:

```
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
```

Here is the output of vagrant up:

```
Bringing machine 'test' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> test: Importing base box 'dev'...
==> test: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> test: Setting the name of the VM: test
==> test: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2200.
==> test: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> test: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    test: Adapter 1: nat
    test: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> test: Forwarding ports...
    test: 22 (guest) => 2200 (host) (adapter 1)
==> test: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> test: Booting VM...
==> test: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    test: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2200
    test: SSH username: username
    test: SSH auth method: password
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.

If the box appears to be booting properly, you may want to increase
the timeout ("config.vm.boot_timeout") value.
```

Vagrant status shows:

```
Current machine states:

test                    running (virtualbox)

The VM is running. To stop this VM, you can run `vagrant halt` to
shut it down forcefully, or you can run `vagrant suspend` to simply
suspend the virtual machine. In either case, to restart it again,
simply run `vagrant up`.
```

Output of ping 192.168.33.10:

```
PING 192.168.33.10 (192.168.33.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.33.1 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.33.1 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.33.1 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I have tried setting public_network instead of private_network in Vagrantfile but no difference [link](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/public_network.html#static-ip).

ifconfig output:

```
ens2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.64.62.141  netmask 255.255.255.254  broadcast 10.64.62.141
        inet6 fe80::dc1c:3cff:fe64:2047  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2001:bc8:47a0:1f46::1  prefixlen 127  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether de:1c:3c:64:20:47  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 764159  bytes 2552235354 (2.5 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 473453  bytes 124372499 (124.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 35498  bytes 451319135 (451.3 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 35498  bytes 451319135 (451.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.33.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.33.255
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 434  bytes 42136 (42.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

route -n output:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.62.140    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens2
10.64.62.140    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 ens2
192.168.33.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 vboxnet0
```

Am I missing something? This box works locally.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that is a huge problem, the first level of VM only can emulate the hardware.

It takes a lot of tuning and custom drivers to make it work.

Run on a bare metal, that is VirtualBox was designed for.

Comment: I see. I have found this as well https://superuser.com/questions/1147113/running-virtual-box-vm-inside-vmware-vm-windows-server-2008. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your vagrant VM freeze on boot and timeout.

by any chance you are running the host on a VM too (VM inception)?

Comment: Vagrant status shows the machine is running, I will update the description. The machine I'm using is a VM too yes. Should that be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had issues with vagrant up. I just relised that i must update powershell and windows management framework
 Now it works properly and faster. Hope it helps.